# java - analyzing big text files

Tags: java, text

I need to analyze a log file at runtime with Java.

What I need is, to be able to take a big text file, and search for a certain string or regex within a certain range of lines.

The range itself is deduced by another search.

For example, I want to search the string `"operation ended with failure"` in the file, but not the whole file, only starting with the line which says `"starting operation"`.

Of course I can do this with plain `InputStream` and file reading, but is there a library or a tool that will help do it more conveniently?

Comment: conveniently - sounds like *lazy loading* :-D

Comment: does it have to be in java? I mean, grep (a *nix standard utility) does exactly that for you... It is a command line tool, though.

Comment: Or use Splunk - http://www.splunk.com

Comment: Can't you just use the Pattern class like they do [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/CalculatingWordFrequencieswithRegularExpressions.htm)?

Comment: well i'm searching for a java solution. though, for las resort i'll use a command line util. any good utils? cna you explain the usage a bit?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is really huge, then in your case either good written java or any *nix tool solution will be almost equally slow (it will be bound to IO). In such a case you won't avoid reading the whole file line-by-line.... And in this case few lines of java code would do the job ... But rather than once-off search I'd think about splitting the file at generation time, which might be much more efficient. You could *redirect* the log file to another program/script (either awk or python would be perfect for it) and split the file on-line/when generated rather than post-factum.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out - http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/

Hope that helps ;)